Linq query filtering null values last in asp net core mvc
I have a table in db name Guest as follows:
Guest1  Guest2  Guest3 Guest4
James
Tom
Jerry   Steve   Jones
Chris   Luke    
Pet     Ron     Rob     James

I want the desirable table below  such that full guests list can appear top in the table and the null values appears last like this
Guest1  Guest2  Guest3 Guest4
 Pet     Ron     Rob     James    
 Jerry   Steve   Jones
 Chris   Luke
 Tom
 James

In the controller I'm doing something like:
 var guestNames = await _db.Guest.ToListAsync();           
 return View(guestNames);

In the view I have a table headers and doing:
    <thead>
    <tr>
     
        <th class="text-center">
          Guest 1
        </th>
    <th class="text-center">
        Guest 2
    </th>
    <th class="text-center">
        Guest 3
    </th>
    <th class="text-center">
        Guest 4
    </th>     
    </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 
 {
 <tr>
    
         <td class="text-center">
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Guest1)
         </td>
     <td class="text-center">
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Guest2)
     </td>
     <td class="text-center">
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Guest3)
     </td>
     <td class="text-center">
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Guest4)
     </td>        

     </tr>
 }

So how do I filter in controller such that I have the desire outcome below?
 Guest1  Guest2  Guest3 Guest4
 Pet     Ron     Rob     James    
 Jerry   Steve   Jones
 Chris   Luke
 Tom
 James


Try somthing like:
var guestNames = await _db.Guest
        .OrderBy(g=>g.Guest1==null)
        .ThenBy(g=>g.Guest2==null)
        .ThenBy(g=>g.Guest3==null)
        .ThenBy(g=>g.Guest4==null)
        .ToListAsync();           
 return View(guestNames);


Thank you! This solved my problem. You're a star! I did this earlier but it didn't work (as it's a string I just replaced the null to "" and it worked so thanks so much).

g.Guest1==null  returns true or false. If you sort by true or false, false comes first in the alphabet.

You're looking to order your list entries, not filter them. Filtering means removing entries that don't fit your criteria.
Essentially, you need to sum the number of "Guest*" properties that are not null in each object.
First, a helper method to count how many properties are not null.
private int GetGuestCount(Guest guest)
{
    var count = 0;
    count += guest.Guest1 is not null ? 1 : 0;
    count += guest.Guest2 is not null ? 1 : 0;
    count += guest.Guest3 is not null ? 1 : 0;
    count += guest.Guest4 is not null ? 1 : 0;
    return count;
}

Then you can use that in an OrderByDescending LINQ method.
var guestNames = await _db.Guest.ToListAsync();
// I'd recommend doing this ordering outside of SQL

var orderedGuestNames = guestNames.OrderByDescending(GetGuestCount);
return View(orderedGuestNames);

Note, if you have any "gaps" in your Guest entry, such as Guest2 being null but 1, 3, and 4 are not, this will still report the count as "3", and be treated as if 1-3 were populated and 4 was null.
You may also want to have a second-level ordering. Why does Tom come before James? You may want to specify how entries should be ordered when the share they same number guests, for example alphabetically ascending by Guest1's name. Look into ThenBy and ThenByDescending to do that.

Side note, it sounds like your database table is oddly designed. Having concrete "Guest#" columns isn't "Normalized". I don't know the whole context of your code, but consider making a table that lists each of the guests for the parent entry, rather than making it a single row.
